# ошибка LNK2005 и LNK1169 в написании простейшего калькулятора

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пытаюсь написать элементарный калькулятор на C++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,b,d;

    char c;

    cout << "Enter first number " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "enter sing" << endl;
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Enter second number " << endl;
    cin >> b;


    switch (c)
    {
    case '+': d = a + b; break;
    case '-': d = a - b; break;
    case '*': d = a*b; break;
    case '/': d = a/b; break;
    }

    cout << "result = " << d;

    system ("pause >> void");
    return 0;
}
```

Но выдаёт 2 ошибки :  LNK2005 и LNK1169
Помогите пожалуйста 2-ух дневному программисту)

Comment: Если вы приведёте _полное_ сообщение об ошибке, нам будет легче догадаться, что пошло не так. Даже среди программистов с бóльшим стажем далеко не все помнят числовые коды ошибок наизусть.

Comment: (И да, зачем вы перенаправляете вывод команды `pause` в файл с названием `void`?)

Comment: @VladD
Ошибка 1 error LNK2005: _main уже определен в main.obj
Ошибка 2 error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более

Comment: Так, это уже лучше. Вы разместили функцию `main` в header'е, что ли? Какие у вас файлы ещё есть в проекте?

Comment: @VladD 
Файл с простейшей функцией вывода текста в консоль, его стоит удалить?

Comment: Это header или cpp-файл? Это важно. Что у вас в файле main.cpp, полностью? И что в этом втором файле (и как он называется)?

Comment: @VladD 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Hello user!" << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
Называется main.cpp

Comment: Ну вот, у вас две функции `main`. Именно на это компилятор и ругается, если вы заглянете в сообщение об ошибке. Уберите ненужную.

Comment: @VladD 
Убрал, но ничего не поменялось

Comment: Не может быть, перекомпилируйтесь. Должно работать. Или ищите ещё одну функцию `main` в проекте. (_Ушёл спать._)

Comment: @VladD
Спокойной ночи.
Постораюсь что нибуть придумать

Comment: @VladD Да! После перезагрузки всё заработало! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @VladD в строке `system("pause>>void");` происходит остановка программы, без вывода сообщения "нажмите любую клавишу".

Comment: @Nik: Это-то понятно, а вот зачем сообщение «нажмите любую клавишу» при этом записывать в **файл на диске** с именем `void`?

Answer (score 2):

Сообщения об ошибке LNK2005 и LNK1169, как подсказывает Гугл, говорят о повторном определении символа (то есть, нарушении правила ODR). Точная ошибка содержит имя символа `_main`, которое является декорированным именем (почитайте где-нибудь, для чего при компиляции нужна декорация имён) функции `main`.

Второго определения `main` в приведённом коде нет. Это означает, что в проекте есть ещё код. Таким образом, возможны два варианта.

- Либо функция `main`, как она дана в вопросе, определена в header'е, и этот header подключается из нескольких cpp-файлов
- Либо функция `main` определена таки в cpp-файле, как и надо, но есть ещё один cpp-файл с другой функцией `main`.

Расследование в комментариях показало, что имеет место второй вариант. Один из `main`'ов нужно удалить, переименовать или хотя бы закомментировать.